# Including values NOT FOUND in MySQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL tables:

tbl_pet_owners:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | name   | pet      | city   | date_adopted |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  2 | jane   | dog      | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  3 | jane   | cat      | Boston | 2017-06-11   |
|  4 | jack   | cat      | Boston | 2016-07-11   |
|  5 | jim    | snake    | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  6 | jim    | goldfish | Boston | 2017-07-11   |
|  7 | joseph | cat      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
|  8 | sam    | cat      | NYC    | 2017-07-11   |
|  9 | drew   | dog      | NYC    | 2016-07-11   |
| 10 | jack   | frog     | Boston | 2017-07-19   |
+----+--------+----------+--------+--------------+
```

tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I have the following SQL query that searches for a list of pet types, along with the name and city of the owner with those pet types:

```
SELECT DISTINCT types.type, owners.name, owners.city
FROM tbl_pet_owners owners
LEFT JOIN tbl_pet_types types ON owners.pet = types.pet
WHERE types.type IN ('mammal', 'fish', 'amphibian', 'seacreature');
```

The query returns:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
| type        | name   | city   |
+-------------+--------+--------+
| mammal      | jane   | Boston |
| mammal      | jack   | Boston |
| fish        | jim    | Boston |
| seacreature | jim    | Boston |
| mammal      | joseph | NYC    |
| mammal      | sam    | NYC    |
| mammal      | drew   | NYC    |
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Amphibian is omitted from the results because it is not found in tbl_pet_types. How can I change my query so that the row:

```
amphibian, NULL, NULL
```

is included in the results?

Comment: Why would you search for a type that didn't exist? Why not search for Elvis? Or Trump?

Comment: @Strawberry I'd like my application to fail gracefully if I user searches for a types that doesn't exist. In other words, I'd like to tell the user that the type they searched for was not found.

Comment: I think I'd handle that in the application logic.

Answer (score 1):

A `left join` is correct, but you need for the `types` to be first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT types.type, owners.name, owners.city
FROM tbl_pet_types types LEFT JOIN
     tbl_pet_owners owners
     ON owners.pet = types.pet
WHERE types.type IN ('mammal', 'fish', 'amphibian', 'seacreature');
```

Because the `WHERE` clause refers only to `tbl_pet_types`, it does not change.

How `left join` works is simple:  It keeps all rows in the *first* table.  Unmatched columns in the second become `NULL`.

EDIT:

If you have a list of types that are not in `tbl_pet_types`, then you need a `left join` with all the values in a derived table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.type, po.name, po.city
FROM (SELECT 'mammal' as type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'fish' as type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'amphibian' as type UNION ALL
      SELECT 'seacreature' as type 
     ) tt left join
     tbl_pet_types pt
     ON pt.type = tt.type LEFT JOIN
     tbl_pet_owners po
     ON po.pet = pt.pet;
```

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff amphibian is still being omitted from the results. I think it's because amphibian is not in tbl_pet_types. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Then perform a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` saying

```
RIGHT JOIN tbl_pet_types types ON owners.pet = types.pet
```

In case you want outer joined result for both table (which not sure off), you can then consider doing a `FULL JOIN` by mixing right and left join

Comment: What a confusing way of expressing such a simple idea

Comment: @Rahul amphibian is still being omitted from the results. I believe it's because amphibian is not in type_pet_types. How can I fix this?

Comment: A `RIGHT JOIN` is little more than a `LEFT JOIN` done backwards. Personally, I'd be happy if `RIGHT JOIN`s were removed from all SQL standards. They can quickly make things very confusing, and to me they usually indicate a query that should be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Does MySQL *STILL* not have CTEs? They make life so much easier.

Regardless, to get 'NOT FOUND', use `coalesce()` in your `SELECT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.petType
    , coalesce(po.name,'NOT FOUND') AS name
    , coalesce(po.city,'NOT FOUND') AS city
FROM (
    SELECT 'mammal' AS petType UNION ALL
    SELECT 'fish' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'amphibian' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'seacreature'
) p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (  
    SELECT tpo.name, tpo.city, pt.type AS petType
    FROM tbl_pet_owners tpo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_pet_types tpt ON tpo.pet = tpt.pet
) po ON p.petType = po.petType
```

I don't have a MySQL machine to test this on, but something like this *should* give you what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to edit your query so I can search for an arbitrary list of pet types?

Comment: Actually, looking at what you're asking, it doesn't look like it's a list of types, but a single input. In that case, it would simply return 0 records and you'd have to programmatically deal with that on your display.

Comment: Are you letting them free-form input the types of pets they'd like to look for? Besides the huge potential for injection, that's just asking for trouble. Provide them with a list of pet types that they can search on, derived from the types you currently have in the db. No pet type, no selection. Problem avoided.

Comment: I'm dealing with a data set of 100,000+ pet types.

Comment: Is there a way to edit your FROM clause to select from a list of pet types?

Comment: How do they choose the pet type? I still think you need to give them a specific list to search from. If you allow them to free-form it, then you'll get 100,001 when they search for 'mamal'.

Comment: Where does your list of pet types come from? Is it already stored in a database table somewhere?

Comment: They come from tbl_pet_types (see above). But I'd like the user to be able to search for an arbitrary list of pet types. I'm taking the necessary precautions to prevent injection.

Comment: Is it possible to edit your FROM clause to SELECT from the user's list of pet types?

Comment: Use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to match up owners and pet types. But I'd still say to not let them choose a pet type that doesn't exist. Make your application user-proof and it'll help keep weird issues from creeping into your code. How does a user create their list of pet types?

Comment: Could I do something like FROM ( SELECT ('mammal', 'fish', 'amphibian', 'seacreature') UNION ALL ) to have the same effect as your current FROM clause?

Comment: That's sort of what I did, but short of building a huge dynamic SQL statement, it won't work that way. I'm still going to go with this being an application issue, not a query issue. I have to agree with @Strawberry's earlier statements. You're trying to `SELECT` something that doesn't exist. The display of 'NOT FOUND' should be handled in the application logic.